# Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal in javascript. I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

This is my code, a simple sequel of function were I generate two number, one for the user, one for the PC and who scores the highest number win the game.
Firefox has come out with Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: string literal error, I checked my code and everything seems ok to me, I can't figure out what's wrong and generates that error

```
// Generate a random number between 1 and 6 both for user and PC.
// Who does the highest score win.

//I create the random number for user and PC
var userNumber = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
var pcNumber = getRandomNumber(1, 6);

console.log(userNumber);
console.log(pcNumber);

//With highestScore function the winner comes out
var whoWon = highestScore(userNumber, pcNumber);
console.log(whoWon);

//I use this function to obtain the random number
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}

//Function highestScore tell who's won the game
//matchMessage tells how the winner or the eventual tie has come
//The return is obviously matchMessage
function highestScore (num1, num2) {
    var matchMessage = 'Your number is ' + num1 ', PC number is ' + num2 ', tie!!';

    if (num1 > num2) {
        matchMessage = 'Your number is ' + num1 ', PC number is ' + num2 ', congrats you've won';
    } else if (num1 < num2) {
        matchMessage = 'Your number is ' + num1 ', PC number is ' + num2 ', you lost...';
    }

    return matchMessage;
}
```

Comment: missing `+` after `+ num 1` on each line. Note that this would be much easier and more readable with template literals.

Comment: It's true, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing a plus `+` sign while adding the strings with variables.

   What you are doing:

   ```
   'Your number is ' + num1 ', PC number is '
   ```

   What it should be:

   ```
   'Your number is ' + num1 + ', PC number is '
   ```

---

2. When you are using the same type of quote in a string then you have two ways to correct it:

   - Use different strings, like:

     ```
     ", congrats you've won"
     ```
   - Or you can escape that string using `\`, Like

     ```
     ', congrats you\'ve won'
     ```

---

Try this:

```js
// Generate a random number between 1 and 6 both for user and PC.
// Who does the highest score win.

//I create the random number for user and PC
var userNumber = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
var pcNumber = getRandomNumber(1, 6);

console.log(userNumber);
console.log(pcNumber);

//With highestScore function the winner comes out
var whoWon = highestScore(userNumber, pcNumber);
console.log(whoWon);

//I use this function to obtain the random number
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

//Function highestScore tell who's won the game
//matchMessage tells how the winner or the eventual tie has come
//The return is obviously matchMessage
function highestScore(num1, num2) {
  var matchMessage = 'Your number is ' + num1 + ', PC number is ' + num2 + ', tie!!';

  if (num1 > num2) {
    matchMessage = 'Your number is ' + num1 + ', PC number is ' + num2 + ', congrats you\'ve won';
  } else if (num1 < num2) {
    matchMessage = 'Your number is ' + num1 + ', PC number is ' + num2 + ', you lost...';
  }

  return matchMessage;
}
```

Comment: You're right, error of attention, thanks, it was under my nose all the time!